# How to select specific windows in i3?

Tags: selection, i3-window-manager

You are able to select all windows to run a command with $mod + a, is it possible to select multiple specific windows at once? For example, wanting to select the two leftmost windows to run a close operation and leaving the rightmost window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the windows you would like to select within their own Navigator container then when you press `$mod+a` it will select those windows. Alternatively, you can stack the windows so that one is on top of two, using `$mod+a` when one of the bottom windows is selecting will only select the bottom two rows.